# Report Builder 3 - Number Format

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, numbers, format

From an application DB (SQL Server 2012) I run a queries to get some data from. I have 3 fields which contains numbers as data type, the problem is the format of these numbers:
[image]

As you can see at the end of each number there is an 'E+15'. But in my application I can see the same data with correct format.
Any ideas what is mean 'E+15' and how can I get this data with correct format?

@Juan, the result of STR()

[image]

Comment: You are looking at very large numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: do you see e+15 numbers in reporting services or ssms?

Comment: @Anup, I see 'E+15' in Report Builder, in SQL Studio and also in SSRS

Comment: What value do you expect to see? Is your sql correct, looks like either your data or your query is generating huge numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Convert or Cast doesnt work in this case. You still will ge scientific notation.

For display USE `STR()`

```
STR(MinValue), STR (MaxValue)
```

Comment: Hi Joan, I edited the my post wit the result of your proposed solution

Comment: I think you didnt provide the complete query. Because that result doesnt make sense